# BASH Script Read username form file and start program

Tags: bash

I'm setting up a BBS and I wan't add irc access. I'm using this script to parse the CHAIN file.

```
#!/bin/bash
NODE=$1 #get the node number
USERNAME= sed -n 2p /mystic/temp$NODE/CHAIN.TXT #read the second line in the chain file.
irssi -n $USERNAME # start irssi
```

but its not working.

Comment: How are you calling this script? What does CHAIN.TXT look like? What is the contents of /mystic ? What exactly do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: The content of /mystic is "temp$NODE/CHAIN.TXT".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
USERNAME=`sed -n 2p /mystic/temp$NODE/CHAIN.TXT`
```

or

```
USERNAME=$(sed -n 2p /mystic/temp$NODE/CHAIN.TXT)
```

i.e. include your command in backquotes. It will actually tell your shell script to execute that command, rather than just assign string value to var `USERNAME`

Comment: Use `$(...)` in favor of backquotes: `USERNAME=$(sed ..)`.

Comment: Added as another option. @chepner I thought those were interchangeable?

Comment: They are, but `$(...)` is more readable in most fonts and can be nested. There isn't much need to use backquotes except to recognize them in older code.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

```
#!/bin/bash
NODE=$1
USERNAME=$(sed -n 2p /mystic/temp$NODE/CHAIN.TXT)  ## Use command substitution.
echo "Username: $USERNAME"  ## Optionally show username for debugging purposes.
irssi -n "$USERNAME"  ## Quote the variable to prevent word splitting and possible pathname expansion.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read multiple lines from a single source using a series of calls to `read` inside a command group.

```
{ read; IFS= read -r USERNAME; } < /mystic/temp$NODE/CHAIN.txt
```

Read but ignore the first line of the file, then read the entire second line and store it in the variable `USERNAME`.